# Make whole div with rotated elements clickable

Tags: html, css

I created a hamburger menu that, when clicked, rotates two of its children and one is hidden. The hamburger has 30px width and 13px height. The thing is: when the two children rotate, the height increases, but only the central area (which is 30px/13px is clickable).

How can I make the whole "X" clickable?

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById("menu-icon-css");
var menuMobile = document.getElementById("menu-links");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function open() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("rotate");
})
```

```css
#menu-icon-css {
  z-index: 50;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 13px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
#menu-icon-css span {
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 6px;
  width: 70%;
  right: 0;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px) {
  #menu-icon-css {
    display: none;
  }
}

#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  top: 6px;
}
#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-icon-css">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I'll leave a print of the issue on Inspect.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try a few tweaks on the main top margin, height of the menu-icon-css div, and the position of the child elements, such as the following. (The lines in your code that I changed, I commented out and replaced with a line containing my changes.)

```
#menu-icon-css {
    z-index: 50;
    //margin-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    width: 30px;
    //height: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
#menu-icon-css span {
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 6px;
    width: 70%;
    right: 0;
}
#menu-icon-css span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 12px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px) {
    #menu-icon-css {
    display: none;
  }
}

#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    //top: 6px;
    top: 14px;
}
#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
}
#menu-icon-css.rotate span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    //top: 6px;
    top: 14px;
}
```